# How to read all the chars into a String from a textfile (using scanner)

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, filereader

I have tried:

```
String input = "";
FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
Scanner in= new Scanner(reader);
input = in.nextLine();
```

This doesnt work as it only reads in the first line, so i change to:

```
String input = "";
FileReader reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
Scanner in= new Scanner(reader);
while(in.hasNextLine()){
input = input + in.nextLine();
}
```

it doesnt work too..because my file is like a manual with several return line and it looks something like this:

Hello world,

You should  code

java    frequently
that's it!

Regards,
     unknown?

Note: i would like to stall everything including the whitespaces and the return feed and all chars into a String, is that possible? Thanks for all guidance provided

Comment: by right there are alot white spaces in between words and certain lines are "newline" many times...in short, it is a messy file. I do not know how to format it in stack to very messy, it auto align all to left

Comment: You need to use `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to read whole file into a string using `Scanner#useDelimiter` method **without loop**:

```
String fileData = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

Comment: it works perfectly, just with alot warnings. Can u explain the useDelimiter onwards? i wish to uds your code.

Comment: In regex `\Z` means end of input (even when there are multiline input) and can be present ONLY once in the input. When `\Z` is used as delimiter that means scanner reads complete file in one go since `\z` is matched only at end of file.

Comment: Thanks, i understand already. Erm can i ask you another qns over here? I used your method, it will work if my file is not too big, but when i tried for a larger file, the string cant hold all the chars, it will just hold from middle to end. Any suggestion to work around this?

Comment: Make sure you're opening a text file not a binary file and for really huge file this method is limited to the heap available to JVM. Try to allocate more heap while starting your program/app.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer(); // java.lang.StringBuffer for this`

Inside your `while(in.hasNextLine())` loop:

```
sbf.append(in.nextLine());
```

After you are done, use `sbf.toString()` to get the string you wanted.

Comment: i tried your method, indeed all char was read but however the paragraphing is not the same when i do a println. I do not know how to express that term, i guess the 'newline' char was not captured into string? i need the exact format

Comment: You could manually add the newline: `sbf.append(in.nextLine() + "\n");`

Comment: will this cater to '\r', '\r\n' too?